# How to measure ECC key size?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, keys, key-size

I have implemented a ECC key generation scheme successfully. Now I need to find ECC key sizes of each generating key pairs. I assumed that ECC key size is the size of the ECC private Key.

So I would like to to know whether this is correct?

Comment: When talking about the size in ECC we generally refer to the field size.

Comment: Then key size of keys generated using secp160r1 elliptic curve is 160 bits?

Comment: Yes, it would be 160 bits. Note that a 160 bit elliptic curve can be broken with approximately $2^{80}$ operations.

Comment: If you use the private key value $S$ itself (which you shouldn't), then you should definitively **not** treat it as an integer. There is nothing to prevent the private key to start with `00` or `0000` to my knowledge. So using `integer(S).bitlength()` or similar may give you the wrong result.

Answer (score 7):

The size we speak of with regard to elliptic curves is the size of the field over which the elliptic curve is defined. This is not necessarily *exactly* the size of the private key.

For example: Curve25519 is a 255-bit elliptic curve and has, effectively, 252-bit private keys, though they are usually encoded as 256-bit values with four fixed bits. Public keys are 256-bit values, but only contain 255 bits of information since the last bit is always 0.

Comment: Nit: Curve25519 has effectively 252 bit private keys; each encoded 256 bit value with 4 bits fixed will map to a distinct member of the 252 bit subgroup that they actually use.

Answer (score 5):

ECC public keys are (X,Y) points where X and Y are elements in a given field (e.g. Fp or F2m).

For example, secp160r1 uses a 160-bit prime field. X and Y can be up to 160 bits long. So (X,Y) is 320 bits.

The (X,Y) point can be represented in compressed form where only the X value and a bit of information is given, since Y is a function of X.

X.962 encoding can be used for these 3 cases. Note that X and Y are zero-padded to the prime modulus size in the case they are smaller:

Uncompressed:

0x04 | X | Y

Compressed (Y is even):

0x02 | X

Compressed (Y is odd):

0x03 | X

Comment: Hi new user and welcome. Unfortunately this is in my opinion not what was asked. I guess the question is: "Given a key, what parameter(s) should I use to retrieve the key size?"

Comment: Whatever you say.

Comment: No need for that kind of comment, please re-read the question and ask yourself if your answer matches.